# Declaring and using variables using WITH clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that uses WITH clause (subquery factoring) and i need to define a variable and assign a value to it to use in a couple of the subqueries within the WITH clause.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

I've tried some ways to define the variable and affect it but i always have syntax error.

Comment: As is, it's not that clear to me what you need to do. Please post some code, clearly explaining what you need to get and the issues with your attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following two methods:

**1. Use within WITH clause**

```
WITH MY_VARIABLE ( VAL ) AS (
    SELECT
        12 -- your variable value goes here
    FROM
        DUAL
), MY_MAIN_WITH_QUERY ( DIFFERENT_COLUMNS ) AS (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        MY_VARIABLE M
    WHERE
        M.VAL > 10 -- the use of a variable in your main query
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MY_MAIN_WITH_QUERY;
```

**2. Use DEFINE**

```
DEFINE VAL=12; -- declaring and assigning value to your variable
WITH MY_MAIN_WITH_QUERY ( DIFFERENT_COLUMNS ) AS (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        DUAL
    WHERE
        &VAL > 10 -- the use of your variable in your query
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MY_MAIN_WITH_QUERY;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can always define your column value in the with clause.

```
with cte as ( select 1 as your_value from dual )
```

Then use it to your need. For example:

```
select your_value from cte
```